# Auto Layout Reversed Constraints in XCode 6.1

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, xcode6.1

This has been an ongoing issue for me and other people I work with.

Someone would expect that the following two constraints would both work since essentially they are the same constraint.

The "end" of Sign Up and "start" of Login should be separated by 15 points

sounds the same as

The "start" of Login and "end" of Sign Up should be separated by 15 points.

Yet, sometimes you have to inverse the constraint to make it work.

Should I file a radar or have we been missing something?

This is on XCode 6.1 but has been going on for sometime now (can't remember the version).

[image]

Comment: I do everything with constraints, and I have never seen this problem. Can you provide a minimal example that shows this problem, and post it somewhere?

Answer (score 4):

You've been missing something.

Constraints express an equation:

```
firstItem.firstAttribute == secondItem.secondAttribute * multiplier + constant
```

(The equation could also use <= or >= instead of ==.)

Swapping the item-attribute terms does not result in the same equation. You would have to negate the constant to maintain the meaning. (You would also have to divide by the multiplier.)

Your left-side screenshot means:

```
Sign Up.Trailing == Login.Leading * 1 + 15
```

Your right-side screenshot means:

```
Login.Leading == Sign Up.Trailing * 1 + 15
```

Subtract 15 from both sides of the latter yields:

```
Login.Leading - 15 == Sign Up.Trailing * 1
```

Drop the multiplication by 1:

```
Login.Leading - 15 == Sign Up.Trailing
```

Swap the two sides:

```
Sign Up.Trailing == Login.Leading - 15
```

Re-express in the standard constraint form:

```
Sign Up.Trailing == Login.Leading * 1 + (-15)
```

Compare to the left-side:

```
 Left side: Sign Up.Trailing == Login.Leading * 1 + 15
Right side: Sign Up.Trailing == Login.Leading * 1 + (-15)
```

They mean different things.

Put another way, the constant is not just a magnitude of the distance, but also the direction, so sign matters. It's very possible to force two views to overlap along a given axis, for example.

Comment: Ok that totally makes sense. But sometimes when reversing the first and second items, XCode does change the constant to "-constant" while some other times it doesn't! Are there any cases where this should be the expected behaviour?

Comment: I don't know why/when Xcode would do that and when it wouldn't. It might have to do with whether the constraint matches the current state of the canvas.

Comment: I hate auto layout :(

Answer (score 0):

They're not the same because your constant is 15. You would need to change the constant in the second constraint to -15.